# Mac OS X / Open terminal with specified windows

Tags: macos, terminal

Is it possible to open a terminal window with 3 tabs. Each tab should have different path.

Example:

```
Tab1: /etc
Tab2: /bin
Tab3: /www/ tail -f file.txt
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is absolutely possible, but it will take some work on your part.  The first thing you need is to set up each window/tab you want in your Settings:

[image: Settings]

I have 4 tabs that I open automagically every time I open Terminal.  `DB Shell`, `Editor`, `Server`, and `Shell`.  These are all within the `Sasquatch` (don't ask) project, thus the naming.  Each of these should then have a unique command associated with them:

[image: startup cmd]

In this case, I'm executing `vim`.  If you happen to have a specific directory you'd like to start off in, you can use something like `vim ~/projects/main/`.  Really whatever you want to go in there is the command the shell will execute when it opens.  Now you need to open all your windows/tabs:

1. Close everything.
2. Open a new window for each of your profiles.

   - Go to the `Shell` menu => `New Tab`/`New Window` => Select the profile you created above.
   - Repeat for each window or tab you want.
3. Once you have all of your windows and/or tabs open, save them as a Window Group.

   - Go to the `Window` menu => `Save Window As Group...`.
   - Give your Window Group a name (this is helpful later).
   - If you want this group to open every time you open Terminal, check the box at the bottom of this screen, and then hit save.
4. Close out of all of your Windows/Tabs (time to test it!).
5. Open your new Window Group.

   - Go to the `Window` menu => `Open Window Group` => Select the group you just made.

This should pop up all the windows you just had, in the same position.  Each of the commands you set up in `Settings` should be launched in their respective tabs.

Comment: Fantastic.
Only thing I'd add is a keyboard shortcut for the window group. 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/mPVDN.png

System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts.
Click + to add shortcut. Just put the window group name in MenuTitle, and then enter the shortcut in the next box.

Comment: I use zsh and tried this answer to create a window group with four tabs each with a different pwd. So, my startup commands were all `cd` commands. However, those startup commands override the setting to [open a new tab in the same directory](http://superuser.com/a/313172/59284) and cause Command-T to run the startup command again for the new tab.

Answer (score 14):

As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal makes this much easier to do, without creating new profiles for each command.

1. By default, Terminal will remember and restore the current working directory for each terminal in a Window Group. (If the working directory has been communicated to Terminal using an escape sequence. The default shell, bash, will do this at every command prompt. For other shells, you'll need to adapt the code in /etc/bashrc.)
2. If you create a terminal with **Shell > New Command**, Terminal will automatically run that command when a Window Group is opened. Terminal will automatically run a limited set of "safe" commands†, and when saving a Window Group there's an option to run all commands in the group.

Terminal also automatically does these for all windows when restarting Terminal with Resume enabled. So, you may not even have to create a Window Group, depending on your circumstances.

For your example case:

1. Use **Shell > New Command** to run "tail -f /www/file.txt".
2. Create a new tab and "cd /etc".
3. Create a new tab and "cd /bin".
4. Save them with **Window > Save Windows as Group**. Be sure to check the "Restore all commands" checkbox.

Each time you open that Window Group, it will recreate those windows and run the commands. If you need to run a command *and* specify the starting directory, in the New Command dialog check the "Run command inside a shell" checkbox and make the command "cd ; ".

Also note that you can tell Terminal to open your Window Group at startup with **Terminal > Preferences > Startup > On startup, open > Window group**. There's even a checkbox to set this when saving a new Window Group.

† The "safe" commands include anything listed in /etc/shells, plus: screen, tmux, emacs, vi/vim, nano, pico, and top. You can customize the list with "defaults write com.apple.Terminal RestorableCommands". Set it to an array of strings containing command names or full paths. Some commands have parameters that are "unsafe" to run automatically without user intervention, so by default these commands are only considered "safe" if they do not have any arguments. To make a command safe to run with arguments, add an asterisk, e.g., "top *" is in the default value for this preference.

Comment: I use zsh. How do I get Terminal to remember and restore the current working directory for each tab in a Window Group?

Comment: @mattdipasquale: Try looking up your question on StackOverflow, and if you don't find a Q&A that matches your question, post a question. For example, if I search for “Terminal restore working directory zsh” I find http://stackoverflow.com/a/7544224/754997 (my answer) in which I link to another Q&A where I provide code for zsh http://superuser.com/a/328148/81175 which also mentions that this code is now part of the Oh My Zsh package. So if you're using OMZ you'll get this automatically.

Comment: Hi, where is the file saved when I click `Window > Save Windows as Group`. I want to keep a copy of this file so that if I ever move to a different machine or something I have physical backup of these files

Comment: @firstpostcommenter To ask a question, create a Q&A.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. I realized that my comment was a duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718835/where-are-os-x-terminal-window-groups-saved

Answer (score 7):

You can do what you wish from within Terminal.

If in Terminal preferences (Settings tab) you create a new profile (or copy one with Duplicate Settings), you can then set each profile to run a command on startup (the "Shell" subgroup within the profile).

Then setup your tabs by using the Shell > New Tab menu to create the new tabs from each of the specific profiles that you created for the three different executables.

Then do the Save Window Group to save the group of tabs (and it will save their profiles as well).

Answer (score 5):

I suggest the use if [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) instead of Terminal.  If only because it is more configurable.  You can script it, but more important to you is that you can create a bookmark folder (one for each tab) and then "open in tabs" which will give you the behavior you seek.

Comment: +1. Looks like this has been superceded by iTerm2, a separate project. I will give this a go!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you can control commands to be executed too.  One of the programs I use creates a single-tab terminal window and arranges to execute a profile-setting script before continuing to the command prompt - the same should be feasible for a multi-tab terminal.  The file is a MacOS X properties XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CommandString</key>
    <string>. /Applications/IBM/informix/demo/server/profile_settings</string>
    <key>FontAntialias</key>
    <false/>
    <key>RunCommandAsShell</key>
    <false/>
    <key>ShowShellCommandInTitle</key>
    <true/>
    <key>TerminalType</key>
    <string>xterm</string>
    <key>WindowTitle</key>
    <string>IDS Command Window</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>IDS Command Window</string>
    <key>type</key>
    <string>Window Settings</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You can click on it and the terminal window is launched, the profile settings are set, and then you have a command prompt to type at.  Presumably, changing the 'dot' command into the '`tail`' command of the question would work; it might be  that the '`RunCommandAsShell`' key set to '`<true\>`' would replace the normal shell with the command - which is perhaps more appropriate for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is by using the Elscripto ruby gem: https://github.com/Achillefs/elscripto. It allows yuo to easily specify terminal tabs using a YAML file

Answer (score 0):

Open the tabs you want and set each one up as you wish, i.e. in tab 1, `cd /etc`, tab 2 `cd /bin` and so on. Now go to Window > Save Windows as Group. Click the checkbox 'Use window group when Terminal starts' and hey presto!

Comment: Though I don't think you can set tabs to actually execute a specific command (i.e. tail, as in the example). Is this possible?

Comment: I think this might be the case only on 10.7 - on 10.6 CWDs are not remembered.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/features/split_panes

"Divide a tab up into multiple panes, each one of which shows a different session. You can slice vertically and horizontally and create any number of panes in any imaginable arrangement."

Answer (score 0):

**How to Create Custom iTerm2 Window Arrangements**

Create a custom keyboard shortcut to automatically spawn a set of windows and splits with processes running.

With  a shortcut cmd+shift+w transform split your window arrangement into 3 panels

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rg8AT-nds1Q