# How to change the default directory in Terminal on Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal

this is my very first question in here since I just started coding, and I hope it's an easy one. Have found likewise questions on here, but none of their solutions seemed to work for me, or I just didn't know how to pull them off. So here goes: 
How do I change the default directory, when I open up Terminal on my Mac version 10.12.4? Whenever I open, it says this of course: 
Last login: Thu May 17 09:02:07 on ttys004
Mikkels-MacBook-Air:~ MikkelMalmros$ 
Then I have to use the "cd desktop/coding" to move to the folder I created for programming. I would like to skip that step, so it automatically opens up in there. I've tried going to preferences and changing "Shell opens with command" thing and put in "cd desktop/coding". Whenever I open up Terminal then, it just says "process done" and I can't write anything at all.

So what am I doing wrong, and is there a way to fix this small problem for me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696757

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the default directory in mac terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696757/set-the-default-directory-in-mac-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

Add 'cd path/to/directory' to .bash_profile

```
'cd path/to/directory'
```

Found at https://superuser.com/questions/193513/how-can-i-change-the-startup-directory-of-my-terminal-on-os-x