# On MacOS Monterey 12.5 all IDE terminal sessions open at $HOME in stead of project root

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh, jetbrains-ide, permission-denied

As usual, not sure what caused the problem. Started laptop as usual.

But now every project i open, opens in $HOME directory instead of start directory, which is project root by default.

Tried vscode, webstorm, intellij - results were the same.

Further investigation have shown, that dragging absolute path to the terminal + enter causes following error:

```
zsh: permission denied: /Users/<MyName>/Code/Local/Rust/http-server
```

I have full read/write permissions, i added FullDiskPermissions to all apps that might need them.

Apps with full disk permissions:
[image: apps with full disk permissions]

I know it sounds like a minor issue, but i code every day and it's really annoying.

Comment: "I  have full read/write permissions" I don't think you do. I tend to believe what the Terminal reports. So you can't even `cd` to walk from home down into a project? What happens when you try it one level at a time? `cd Code` then `cd Local` and so on.

Comment: @matt sorry, had to write it initally:
 `cd /Users/<MyName>/Code/<companyName>/extractor` works fine.

Comment: Then there is no problem, I take it, except that the terminal doesn't actually _open_ into that project. In other words, you are expecting the terminal to open with a certain directory as its _working directory_ and it isn't. I don't know why you expect that. It isn't something that happens all by itself; you have to configure it. You can read pages like this one if you want to know how to set the working directory on launch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696757/set-the-default-directory-in-mac-terminal

Comment: @matt hmm, i guess the main problem is - in jetbrains/vscode default settings are to open terminal in project folder. And at the moment they are not doing that.
If you take a look at this screenshot, you'll see - each project have starting folder at the project root, but it's not used for some reason.
[Image](https://imgur.com/VJSkjJF).

Comment: So now you're asking a very specific question about the behavior of a particular app. You should probably start over; delete this question and ask that one instead. Give specifics about how you've set the app up, and prove that the target folder does in fact exist; so far you've said that `cd /Users/<MyName>/Code/<companyName>/extractor` works but that is not what it says in that screen shot, so there's a disconnect somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

It's not actually an answer, i still don't know what solved it. But i somehow managed to resume the old behaviour.

The problem was global, terminal was opening in the wrong path everywhere, even from the Finder.

I reinstalled zsh, oh-my-zsh, volta (node.js version control tool) - so make sure to check if you have any of the following installed.

And after a day torture it suddenly started working as it used to.

Comment: This is nice but it's not helpful to others, and Stack Overflow is no one's personal blog. Plus this was never really a programming question, it seems.