# Mac OS X / Open terminal with specified windows *on specified desktops*

Tags: macos, terminal

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150380/mac-os-x-open-terminal-with-specified-windows) explains how to create a "window group" in Terminal.app so that you can open a set of windows with predefined tabs executing predefined commands in predefined positions.

That's great, but it doesn't appear to play nice with Mission Control.  I save my window group with the windows spread out across different desktops in Mission Control, but when I restore the window group they all pile up on top of each other in the desktop I'm currently using!

How can I get a Window Group to restore the windows to the desktops from which I saved them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like separating application windows by desktop is an option anymore; not according to [this MacForums thread](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-operating-system/257121-how-disable-grouping-mission-control.html).

There's an app called [TotalSpaces](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/) that claims to restore pre-Mission Control window grouping, but it's a paid app so I haven't tried it.

You might be better off asking this question on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)...