# Where are OS X Terminal Window Groups saved

Tags: macos, terminal

I know you can save Window Groups in Terminal using Windows > Save Windows as Group…, as explained in [Mac OS X / Open terminal with specified windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150380/mac-os-x-open-terminal-with-specified-windows).

However, where does Terminal save these states? I switch between an iMac and MacBook and want to sync these settings somehow. I'm thinking I could use a reverse symlink between the settings and Dropbox, but I need to know where they are first.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a wild limb and say `/Users/username/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState/`.

Comment: Thanks Pretesh but it was in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist as mpounsett mentioned below

Comment: @Petesh I'm trying to restore the "last window session" from terminal, but there is no `com.apple.Terminal.savedState/` in my `~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/` directory. Do you have any clues about how to find it?

Comment: Hi @ziggurism the answer below is where you should find the information. My guess was incorrect.

Comment: @Petesh No, the `.plist` file in `~/Library/Preferences` only stores preferences, not window state. I guess mpounsett's suggestion would help if you have some window states stored in preferences. But I'm asking about the last session window state, which is NOT stored in preferences.

Comment: @ziggurism I've looked on my laptop and the folder is there with a few files in there so it appears to be a 'works on my machine' issue. If you're having problems with this I'd suggest looking over at [AskDifferent.se](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197129/how-to-restore-manually-saved-state-files-of-terminal) as it's more of an apple particular thing, rather than a programming problem.

Comment: @Petesh which folder is where, on your system? What path are you looking at exactly, so I may compare against mine?

Comment: Exactly the location as mentioned on my first comment, which is why I said 'works on my machine'. This is why I'm suggesting asking a question over on AskDifferent (and I linked to a question which is talking about the corruption of saved window state in `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState/`so it does appear to be the correct location).

Comment: @Petesh I guess the problem was that Time Machine doesn't back up `Saved Application State`, that's why I found it missing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Window groups are saved in a plist file at ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist.  You an edit these using the plist file editor that comes with XCode ('open .apple.Terminal.plist' from a shell is sufficient if you've got XCode installed).

Fortunately you don't have a catch-22 when editing this file from a Terminal window.  Terminal doesn't automatically checkpoint the file on exit, so you can edit the file, exit Terminal, then restart your Mac in order to refresh the data from the file.

Comment: Great, I'll symlink this file to my Dropbox so that I can share preferences between Macs. Thanks