# Gulp – How Can I Open A New Tab In Terminal?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I know little about OSX's Terminal, but I'd like to automatically open tabs in terminal via gulp, and then run gulp commands in them using something like gulp-shell.  For instance, I'd like to have one gulp task that launches mongoDB in on terminal tab, and launches my app in another tab.  How can I do this?

Comment: This answer can give you some hint - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150380/mac-os-x-open-terminal-with-specified-windows/2472623#2472623

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, I had to start mongodb and then scala server. Take a look on this answer, it helped me. 
[Running a command with gulp to start Node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048029/running-a-command-with-gulp-to-start-node-js-server/28048696#28048696)

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
gulp.task('server', function (cb) {
  exec('node lib/app.js', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
  exec('mongod --dbpath ./data', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
})
```

Comment: Hello, I try your answer and did not work for me, it did not open a new terminal, did you set up any other dependency?