# Using Gulp to manage opening and closing MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gulp, nodemon

So far I have a child_process that executes 'mongod --dbpath db' and another child_process which can kill it with 'mongod --dbpath db --shutdown'. How do I listen for the user to enter ctrl-c or exit the gulp runner, and then run the gulp task to shutdown mongo?

Answer (score 6):

I was trying something similar and came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28048696/46810). I refactored it a little to just be the run command function. Functionally there should be no difference between `--shutdown` and the command I'm using.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function runCommand(command) {
  return function (cb) {
    exec(command, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log(stdout);
      console.log(stderr);
      cb(err);
    });
  }
}

//Running mongo
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/28048696/46810
gulp.task('start-mongo', runCommand('mongod --dbpath ./data/'));
gulp.task('stop-mongo', runCommand('mongo --eval "use admin; db.shutdownServer();"'));
gulp.task('start-app', runCommand('node app.js'));
```

Answer (score 2):

@QueueHammer's response was very helpful, but to get this running for my particulars (OSX, MongoDB 3.0.1) it took the following:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var mkdirs = require('mkdirs');

var runCommand = function(command) {
  exec(command, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    if (err !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + err);
    }
  });
}

gulp.task("mongo-start", function() {
  var command = "mongod --fork --dbpath "+paths.dbDir+"/ --logpath "+paths.dbLogs+"/mongo.log";
  mkdirs(paths.dbDir);
  mkdirs(paths.dbLogs);
  runCommand(command);
});

gulp.task("mongo-stop", function() {
  var command = 'mongo admin --eval "db.shutdownServer();"'
  runCommand(command);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To further add on to the above answers, if you'd like a platform-independent solution that works in any OS/environment.  You can use docker.

So you're gulp task would be something like:

```
const Gulp = require('gulp');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

function runCommand(command) {
  return function (cb) {
    exec(command, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log(stdout);
      console.log(stderr);
      cb(err);
    });
  };
}


// Database tasks
Gulp.task('start-mongo', runCommand('docker run --rm --name mongo-dev -p 27017:27017 mongo'));
Gulp.task('start-mongo-viewer', runCommand('docker run --rm --name mongo-express-dev --link mongo-dev:mongo -p 8081:8081 mongo-express'));
```