# gulp with nodemon, watch for file changes, "app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting"

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm trying to automate a simple gulp task to run/debug node, watch for file changes, and restart node if any files change. Most popular recipes I've seen for this use [`gulp-nodemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nodemon), but when a file change event occurs, (gulp-) `nodemon` crashes:

```
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The crashing happens inconsistently, so sometimes I have to manually send a `SIGINT` to stop the node process (which kind of defeats the purpose of nodemon). 
I want to be able to run a gulp task that can watch files, run *or debug* node. How can this be accomplished without nodemon crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not fancy, but the following should accomplish what you want.

```
  'use strict'
   const gulp = require('gulp');
   const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

   gulp.task('debug', function() {
    let child = spawn("node", ["debug", "./server.js"], { stdio: 'inherit' });
    gulp.watch([__dirname + "/*.js", '!gulpfile.js'], function(event) {
        console.log(`File %s was %s.`, event.path, event.type);
        if (child) {
            child.kill();
            child = spawn("node", ["debug", "./server.js"], { stdio: 'inherit' });
        }
    });
});
```

This assumes you're watching for changes to any `js` files in `__dirname` except for your gulpfile.