# npm run script: node server.js && mocha test

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js

My use case is pretty simple:

First I want to run `node server.js`(start my Node.js app) - and **after Node has started** - I want to run `mocha test` (running some tests on the API provided by previous `server.js`) by executing `npm run test`.

The script: `"test": "NODE_ENV=development node server.js && mocha test"`

Node starts, but unfortunately the `mocha test`does not seem to be executed:

[image]

So how can I execute `mocha test` after `node server.js`?

Comment: What kind of web server is your `server.js` running Express, Koa, Node Core HTTP/HTTPS? Its worth noting that as long as you're listening for connections with `node server.js` then anything after that will not be executed because the process won't stop executing.

Comment: @peteb it is running Express

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you're running into this is because `node server.js` continuously runs until killed (Ctrl + C) or a fatal unhandled exception occurs. Since the `node` process keeps running `mocha test` never get executed.

One approach to this would be to use [`gulp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) as a task runner and utilize tasks implementing [`gulp-nodemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nodemon) and [`gulp-mocha`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-mocha). If you've never used Gulp before or are unfamiliar with task runners I suggest you read the docs beforehand just to get an idea of how it works.

Add the `gulpfile.js` below to your app (adjust some of the settings as necessary) and modify your `package.json` scripts with the `test` script below and this should solve your issue.

#### gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var mocha = require('gulp-mocha');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

gulp.task('nodemon', (cb) => {
  let started = false;

  return nodemon({
    script: 'server.js'
  })
    .on('start', () => {
      if (!started) {
        started = true;
        return cb();
      }
    })
    .on('restart', () => {
      console.log('restarting');
    });

});

gulp.task('test', ['nodemon'], function() {
  return gulp.src('./test/*.js')
    .pipe(mocha({reporter: 'spec' }))  
    once('error', function() {
        process.exit(1);
    })
    .once('end', function() {
      process.exit();
    });
});
```

#### package.json `scripts`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=development gulp test"
  }
}
```

#### Supertest Alternative

A more elegant solution ,and in my opinion the better option, would be to rewrite your tests to use [`supertest`](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest). Basically what you do with `supertest` is pass your Express instance to it and run assertions tests against it with the `supertest` package.

```
var mocha = require('mocha');
var request = require('supertest');
var server = require('server');

describe('test server.js', function() {

    it('test GET /', function(done) {
        request(server)
            .get('/')
            .expect(200, done);
    });

});
```

Comment: I implemented your solution and if I run `npm run test` I get a `sh: development: command not found`. The space between `development` and `=` in the test script has to be removed.

Comment: Do you have a solution where `node` is used instead of `nodemon`?

Comment: @Marcel See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048029/running-a-command-with-gulp-to-start-node-js-server) it shows you how to do that.

Comment: @peteb i used supertest, When i starts test. It shows both mixing of app logs, test logs. i dont want that. i want after complete app start, test should start. I also used settimeout function. but it is not giving proper result.

Answer (score 1):

add this code to your test case

```
after(function (done) {
        done();
       process.exit(1);
 })
```