# How can I spawn multiple gulp watch tasks in respective terminals?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I currently have three gulp tasks, leveraging [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch). They are basic in nature, and are represented (simplified) as such...

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('watch:a', function() {
    return watch('a/**/*.js', function () {
        // [...]
    });
});

gulp.task('watch:b', function() {
    return watch('b/**/*.js', function () {
        // [...]
    });
});

gulp.task('watch:c', function() {
    return watch('c/**/*.js', function () {
        // [...]
    });
});
```

However, with my current workflow, I'm forced to open three terminals, and fire them off individually.

---

Is there a way I can instead have one gulp task, which spawns three separate terminal windows with each task running? I have looked into [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) but have not been able to craft a solution. Ideally, I'm visualizing something as such...

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    launchProcess('gulp watch:a');
    launchProcess('gulp watch:b');
    launchProcess('gulp watch:c');
});
```

Where `launchProcess` has some magic so I can consolidate these into one command. I'm simply searching for convenience here, since there could be more than three processes. I cringe at the thought of manually firing tons of these processes off.

---

Here is my initial attempt, taken from [Answer: Gulp – How Can I Open A New Tab In Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30941055/1464112), but this (just trying to fire one watcher) does not let my watcher task work as expected - nothing happens on a file change.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('watch', function(cb) {

    exec('gulp watch:a', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        cb(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own solution isn't really what I expected from your question because, as you said yourself, it's not opening new terminal tabs or anything.

If you're happy with that, the below line will have the same effect as your answer. It also avoids `gulp.start()` which isn't recommended for use by the authors of Gulp.

```
gulp.task('watch', ['watch:a', 'watch:b', 'watch:c']);
```

Or if possible you could always combine your watch tasks like below. Although you then lose the ability to run those tasks individually if that's something you want to do.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    watch('a/**/*.js', function () {
        // [...]
    });

    watch('b/**/*.js', function () {
        // [...]
    });

    watch('c/**/*.js', function () {
        // [...]
    });
});
```

Comment: I like the one-liner. Perhaps I was confused, but I thought at one point these hanging watch tasks needed to be running in their own separate instance, but I'm happy to see it's working as expected. I'll accept your answer as it is cleaner. And yes, this is the behavior I was after since I thought I *needed* separate terminals (tabs) but I'm not seeing that constraint. Would still love to know if spawning terminal windows is possible, that one is still escaping me. Cheers

Comment: Watches don't necessarily have to be in their own task. It's _usually_ good to separate tasks to cleanly return the stream from each. As your watches all have `return` statements, other tasks waiting on them will know when they're finished. My task with three watches combined doesn't return anything so you lose that (unless you use something like [merge-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream)). But other tasks normally don't depend on watch tasks completing (since they are ongoing tasks that don't really end) so it's fine in this case to not return the stream, if that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found perhaps an unconventional way to pull this off, given the deprecation comments on [this gulp.js project issue](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/770), but all testing indicates this will work as expected. I can simply call `gulp.start()`, which, I do not see in the [gulp.js API docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md). Hm, seems good to me...

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.start('watch:a');
    gulp.start('watch:b');
    gulp.start('watch:c');
});
```

All tasks seems to be listening appropriately in a single terminal instance. I'll take it!