# How do I open a new terminal and run a command with Gulp.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm using gulp.js to run a few task

What I need gulp to do is to run some command in a new terminal
e.g:

`cd <directory_name>
 yarn start`

or
 run other command like yarn install or build

That above has to be done in a new terminal.

When I run the first task it will be to open a new terminal and run the serve that is inside a child directory. The second to run the frontEnd project so it will need to open another new terminal and run a command.

I check out this two question on stackOverflow and still not getting what I need.

- [Gulp – How Can I Open A New Tab In Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175150/gulp-how-can-i-open-a-new-tab-in-terminal/30941055#comment84795465_30941055)
- [Running a command with gulp to start Node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048029/running-a-command-with-gulp-to-start-node-js-server/28048696#28048696)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to check [ShellJs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) and [gulp-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell) if you are trying to run Unix shell commands within Gulp. If you are specifically looking to open a new terminal in your GUI, you could attempt to run one the following commands (depending on your Operating System):

```
gnome-terminal -e command
```

or

```
xterm -e command
```

or

```
konsole -e command
```

pretty much:

```
terminal -e command
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/

... with either ShellJs or gulp-shell from a gulp task.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this solution?

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('node exec', function (cb) {
  exec('cd some/where && yarn start', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
});
```

It `Spawns a shell then executes the command within that shell` according to the node.js doc, exactly doing what you want: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it do run the command and that is one step that I need to do, but it don't open a new terminal so if I'm running a server he need his own terminal and another terminal for the frontend end project.